# WampServer files upload

Tags: php, wampserver

i have created a PHP page and i tested it on local wampserver.
 Now i want to upload my PHP page on the web host so it will be live on my website. But, what are other files i should copy from wampserver folder `C:\wampserver` beside my php page i should upload to my server ?? so i will not get errors.
 
knowing that there is a `php.ini` file on my web host already
i have tried to upload my php file alone but iam getting this error

> Warning: mail(/var/log/phpmail.log): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /www1/xxx/Car.php on line 180.

OR is there any other way to solve this problem ?

Comment: That is an error in that it does not have access to the log-folder defined for mail() - this should be fixed on the server, not by uploading files. Really, if you do not know what you're doing, you should not be using a stand-alone server like this, because you're gonna mess things up and leave it open for attack. But check the settings for where you store mail()-logs, or modify the ownership of the file.

Comment: i tried to create new folder on the server with same name and with same path then file phpmail.log and with 705 pernissions but nothing happened

Comment: Check the server logs for more information about exactly what is failing.

Comment: ou are right looks like i messed up with my server  and dont know what to do even the log folder there is no any log files inside it ... iam stuck

Comment: You cannot copy PHP config files from a Windows WAMPServer to a Unix OS and expect things to work! And what happened to your last question?

Comment: @RiggsFolly still same problems for the file upload size and the problem is that its working perfectly on wampserver also i have a php.ini on the live server and i cant change anything in it but its same like the local server ...so please if you have a link or reference for the php config can you send me

Comment: You should only need to restore your database to a database on th server and your web site folder in its entirity. Remember to modify any database connection code to use the database on the server

Answer (score 0):

the `php.ini`  file was not correct and host of the server has been modified by the host company